# lines on plot in r sometimes don't draw

Tags: r, plot, lines

i have the following code to demonstrate that sometimes lines in r on plots don't draw. I can't find the pattern, or issue preventing this, I have even reversed coordinates as can be seen in my 5th and 6th line attempts, tried within plot bounds etc, for the life of me can't understand this

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
myColors=c("red","green","blue","orange","pink","purple")

df<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)), c("Person","yearsExp", "yearsStudy"))
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(1,0,0)
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(2,0,3)
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(3,3,0)
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(4,3,3)
    plot(df$yearsExp,df$yearsStudy,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,main=title,pch=pchvector,col=colvector,type="n",xlim=c(0,3),ylim=c(0,3))
    text(df$yearsExp,df$yearsStudy,labels=df$Person)

    # will draw
    lines(c(1.9,1.9), c(2.0,2.4), pch=16, col=myColors[3],type="l")
    lines(c(1.3,1.2), c(1.8,1.1), pch=16, col=myColors[2],type="l")
    lines(c(1.7,1.1), c(1.3,1.9), pch=16, col=myColors[1],type="l")
    # wont draw
    lines(c(0.0,0.0), c(3.0,3.0), pch=16, col=myColors[6],type="l")
    lines(c(0.1,0.1), c(1.3,1.3), pch=16, col=myColors[5],type="l")
    lines(c(1.3,1.3),c(0.1,0.1), pch=16, col=myColors[4],type="l")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `x` and `y` input of `lines`.

```
lines(c(0.0, 0.0), c(3.0, 3.0))
```

draws a line from `(0, 3)` to `(0, 3)` which is single point.

I guess you meant

```
lines(c(0, 3), c(0, 3))
```

which draws a straight line between points `(0, 0)` and `(3, 3)`.

For example:

```
plot(df$yearsExp,df$yearsStudy,type="n",xlim=c(-1,4),ylim=c(-1,4))
text(df$yearsExp,df$yearsStudy,labels=df$Person)
lines(c(0, 3), c(0, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i think i get what your saying, instead of (x,y) to (x2,y2) it should be (x,x2) to (y,y2). thanks, that actually makes sense, is bleeding obvious now.

Comment: @AbBennett Correct. In `lines(x, y)` `x` is a `numeric` vector of x coordinates; `y` is a `numeric` vector of y coordinates; points are then connected with straight lines.

Comment: @AbBennett  If this answered your question,  please accept the answer.